# Microsoft Excel Formula 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel

i want to know how to make a cell see what is in the column next to it and do the opposite.

E.g. If F4 is Yes then G4 should be No and visa versa

Comment: You could show your efforts on doing some research on your issue and then share the results with the community. Otherwise, your question sounds bluntly as Google search inquiry.

Comment: What if it's blank?

Answer (score 1):

In **G4** enter:

```
=IF(F4="Yes","No","Yes")
```